# how to find duplicates but considering two columns at the same time?

Tags: r, dplyr, duplicates, sum, dataset

This is a sample of my dataset

```
> head(dataset, 20)
   nquest nord tpens
1     173    1  1800
2     633    1   300
3     633    1   600
4     923    1   500
5    2886    1  1211
6    2886    2  2100
7    5416    1   700
8    7886    1  1800
9    7886    1   200
10  20297    1  1200
11  20711    2  2000
12  22169    1   600
13  22169    1   280
14  22173    2  1000
15  22276    1  1200
16  22286    1   850
17  22286    2   650
18  22657    1  1400
19  22657    2  1500
20  23490    1  1400
```

The variables are:

1. `nquest` = is the code of the family to which the individual belong
2. `nord` = is the position of the individual in the family ( 1=husband, 2=wife, 3= son, etc..)
3. `tpens` = is the wage that each one of them earn

I need to find out if for a specific individual there are more than one value for the variable `tpens`. To identify a single person it is fundamental to take into account both `nquest` and `nord` because they have to be the same on different rows. To be more clear

[image: Dataset]

How can I compute how many observations referred to the same individual I have?

I've tried

```
dim(dataset[duplicated(dataset$nquest & dataset$nord),])[1]

sum(duplicated(dataset$nquest & dataset$nord))
```

But I'm pretty sure it is the wrong code, because they sum all the `nquest` that are the equal and do the same for `nord`. Actually, I need the sum when BOTH have the same vale at the same time

Comment: `aggregate(tpens~., df, length)`

Comment: hi @onyambu , R replies <<Error in aggregate.data.frame(lhs, mf[-1L], FUN = FUN, ...) : >>

Comment: did you use `df` or the name of your dataset? ie `aggregate(tpens~., dataset, length)`??

Comment: @onyambu `dataset` of course

Comment: Cant tell why there is an error. Try writting the whole formula ie `tpens~nquest + nord`. Might be an issue with version.

Comment: @onyambu ok, now it works, thanks ... is there a way to check if all the other variables that I have in the dataset referred to these individuals have the same values?

Comment: Yes. That is exactly what the code did. It counted all those `tpens` such that `nquest and nord` were same. So when you see a value like 2, it means that that individual had two tpens. Whether the tpens were same or not.

Comment: @onyambu how can I remove all the rows that have the same `nquest` and the same `nord` in my dataset?

Comment: I am unable to understand your question. Check the solutions below. If none answers your question, consider including the expected output in your question using the data you provided.

Comment: @onyambu sorry, I try to be clear. Now that i've find out all the duplicate values of my dataset, how can I delete them?

Comment: simple `subset(df, !(duplicated(df[1:2]) | duplicated(df[1:2], fromLast = TRUE)))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
subset(df, !(duplicated(df[1:2]) | duplicated(df[1:2], fromLast = TRUE)))

# A tibble: 14 × 3
   nquest  nord tpens
    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1    173     1  1800
 2    923     1   500
 3   2886     1  1211
 4   2886     2  2100
 5   5416     1   700
 6  20297     1  1200
 7  20711     2  2000
 8  22173     2  1000
 9  22276     1  1200
10  22286     1   850
11  22286     2   650
12  22657     1  1400
13  22657     2  1500
14  23490     1  1400
```

Answer (score 2):

First group by the variables that identify your observations, then filter those combinations that appear more than once:

```r
library(tidyverse)

# define dummy data
df <- tibble::tribble(
      ~nquest, ~nord, ~tpens,
     173,    1,  1800,
     633,    1,   300,
     633,    1,   600,
     923,    1,   500,
    2886,    1,  1211,
    2886,    2,  2100,
    5416,    1,   700,
    7886,    1,  1800,
    7886,    1,   200,
   20297,    1,  1200,
   20711,    2,  2000,
   22169,    1,   600,
   22169,    1,   280,
   22173,    2,  1000,
   22276,    1,  1200,
   22286,    1,   850,
   22286,    2,   650,
   22657,    1,  1400,
   22657,    2,  1500,
   23490,    1,  1400
  )

# count combinations of nquest and nord that appear more than once
df |> 
  count(nquest, nord) |> 
  filter(n > 1)
#> # A tibble: 3 × 3
#>   nquest  nord     n
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <int>
#> 1    633     1     2
#> 2   7886     1     2
#> 3  22169     1     2
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-10 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

A more specialized option is to use the package janitor:

```r
janitor::get_dupes(df, nquest, nord)
```

Comment: Thanks for `janitor::get_dupes(df, nquest, nord)` I like it!

Comment: @dufei thank fo the help! is there a way to check if all the other variables that I have in the dataset referred to these individuals have the same values?

Comment: Yes, in fact using the same code. If there are no duplicates, then there is only one row for each combination of nquest and nord.

Comment: @dufei how can I remove all the rows that have the same `nquest` and the same `nord` in my dataset?

Comment: Depends on how you would like to aggregate the duplicate rows. To always just select the first row for each combination, use `df |> group_by(nquest, nord) |> slice_head(n = 1L)`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in all duplicated records, you can use this

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

df[, .SD[.N > 1], .(nquest, nord)]

#    nquest nord tpens
# 1:    633    1   300
# 2:    633    1   600
# 3:   7886    1  1800
# 4:   7886    1   200
# 5:  22169    1   600
# 6:  22169    1   280
```

If you want to remove all those above

```
df[!df[, .SD[.N > 1], .(nquest, nord)], on = c("nquest", "nord")]

#    nquest nord tpens
# 1:    173    1  1800
# 2:    923    1   500
# 3:   2886    1  1211
# 4:   2886    2  2100
# 5:   5416    1   700
# 6:  20297    1  1200
# 7:  20711    2  2000
# 8:  22173    2  1000
# 9:  22276    1  1200
# 10:  22286    1   850
# 11:  22286    2   650
# 12:  22657    1  1400
# 13:  22657    2  1500
# 14:  23490    1  1400
```

**Update**

If you want to keep the first one of the duplicates

```
df[, .SD[1], .(nquest, nord)]
```

If you want to keep the last one of the duplicates

```
df[, .SD[.N], .(nquest, nord)]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update:
If we want to keep the unique values then:**

```
 df[!duplicated(df[,1:2]),]

 nquest  nord tpens
    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1    173     1  1800
 2    633     1   300
 3    923     1   500
 4   2886     1  1211
 5   2886     2  2100
 6   5416     1   700
 7   7886     1  1800
 8  20297     1  1200
 9  20711     2  2000
10  22169     1   600
11  22173     2  1000
12  22276     1  1200
13  22286     1   850
14  22286     2   650
15  22657     1  1400
16  22657     2  1500
17  23490     1  1400
```

**If we want to find the duplicates in column 1 and 2, then:**

```
df[duplicated(df[,1:2]),]
```

output:

```
 nquest nord tpens
3     633    1   600
9    7886    1   200
13  22169    1   280
```

Comment: hi @TarJae and thank for the answer ! how can I remove all the rows that have the same `nquest` and the same `nord` in my dataset now?

Comment: Very simple : `df[!duplicated(df[,1:2]),]` Just use `!`

Comment: If you want to remove them both, you could use Tarjae's approach as well and use `df[!(duplicated(df[, 1:2], fromLast = F) | duplicated(df[, 1:2], fromLast = T))]`